# React Native Navigation Account Log in

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am creating a React Native App with an account handling system. I am using async storage to store the accounts and I have a boolean stored isLoggedIn which I am accessing to see if I should direct the user to the account sign in page or the mainContainer page, but I am confused what would be the best way to do this.

This is my current code, but it always leads to the log in screen no matter what, even when the console outputs true, indicating the user is logged in.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // AsyncStorage.clear();
    async function checkItem() {
      console.log('starting program')
      try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('loggedIn');
        if (value == null || JSON.parse(value) == false) {
          setIsLoggedIn(false);
          console.log('found');
          console.log(value);
        } else {
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
          console.log(value);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    }
    checkItem();
  }, []);
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator 
      
      initialRouteName={isLoggedIn ? 'MainContainer' : 'LogIn'}
      screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false
          }}>

        <Stack.Screen name={'MainContainer'} component = {MainContainer}/>
        <Stack.Screen name = {'LogIn'} component = {LogIn}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Follow-up question: My current plan is to use a stack navigator to lead to the main container hosting the main app or the login screen. The main container has its own tab navigator which it will use. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question about your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work for login flow since you extract login status **after** the Navigation Stack is rendered. And `initialRouteName` only work when navigator is on first load. So, it will always use 'LogIn' page as the first page.

React Navigation suggested [Authentication flows](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow) in their documents. You may follow the guide to create login flow. They suggest to use **conditional renders** by state to render pages.

```
return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false
      }}
    >
      {
        isLoggedIn ?
        <Stack.Screen name={'MainContainer'} component = {MainContainer}/>
        :
        <Stack.Screen name = {'LogIn'} component = {LogIn}/>
      }
    </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

For the follow up question, you can nested the navigator into another one simply follow React Navigation documents - [Screen options with nested navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution#setting-parent-screen-options-based-on-child-navigators-state). In your Stack.Screen MainContainer, you can just put a tab navigator into it.

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MainContainer() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={AccountScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

...

<Stack.Screen name={'MainContainer'} component = {MainContainer}/>
```